# How can I package my Java Maven desktop app with Netbeans 12.6 so that it can be installed on multiple operating systems?

Tags: java, maven, installation, netbeans, packaging

I've been searching high and low for answers for this, but it has proved pretty hard. Maybe I'm just not searching for the right thing, but I'm not sure.

Essentially, I have an app. I want it to work on my Windows system and another MacOS system. I'd also like it to be installed as you would an application made for the average computer user. I know I can run it from the console with java -jar, but I'm more hoping to get some kind of installer, like the .exe/.msi files you get from C# and VS Studio.

I've found a lot of solutions, but very few are up to date (either broken links or depreciated) and even less mention using the Netbeans Maven projects. For example, mosto of the advice I've seen so far says:

1. Clean and build
2. Run the .jar file from the dist folder in the PROJECT_HOME parent folder

The issue is the doing the clean and build action with a Netbeans Maven project doesn't create a dist folder. And anyway, this doesn't help me make a clean, neat desktop application which is installed in the way most people are used to.

Does anyone know how to do this, or can anyone point me in the direction of some relevant documentation I can check? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, this type of question is explicitly off-topic here. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. Also, _"can be installed on multiple operating systems"_ directly conflicts with _"like the .exe/.msi files you get from C# and VS Studio"_, which work only on Windows.  At a minimum you'd need separate versions for each OS, each of which includes an entire JRE _for the target architecture_.

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For building your application into a jar file, run `mvn clean package` which should create a `target` folder which contains the jar. Also, consider looking into the configuration for <s>`maven-jar-plugin`</s> `maven-shade-plugin` and `maven-assembly-plugin` to customize the jar more.

For creating an installer for your application such as an .exe or .msi file, I'd recommend using `Inno Setup` ([link](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)) or maybe look into `jpackage` depending on your Java version and environment.

Comment: To create such setup the maven-jar-plugin is the wrong way. Things like maven-shade-plugin or maven-assembly-plugin are more appropriate.

Comment: I've amended my answer in accordance to your suggestion @khmarbaise